# MongoDB C#: ID Serialization best pattern

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a class `User` and I need to work with them in web services.

Then problem is that if I try to serialize `Id` that is type of `BsonObjectId`, I see
that have an empty property, that have an empty property, and so on ...

I have write this workaround in order, it's is a good solution?

```
public partial class i_User 
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(BsonObjectIdGenerator))]
    [NonSerialized]
    public BsonObjectId _id;

    public String Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id.ToString();
        }
    }   
}
```

In this way, I can keep `_Id` as `BsonObjectId` but I send an string representation over the web in the property `Id`.

Another solution is to work with `StringObjectIdGenerator`

```
public partial class i_User 
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    public String id;
}
```

But is see that MongoDB will store a `string` into database instead of `ObjectId`.

What is the best approach in order to work in a serialization environmental like web services and/or an client-server (Flash+C#)?

Answer (score 102):

If I understand you correctly, you want to access the `Id` property as a string, but have the `Id` saved as an `ObjectId` in MongoDB. This can be accomplished using `BsonRepresentation` with `BsonId`.

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Details can be found [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-RepresentationSerializationOptions).

Comment: This works but is not fully what I hoped for. My wish is to keep my POCO class free from ALL dependencies to Mongo. Is there no way to accomplish this in the BsonClassMap, moving it to the repository layer?

Comment: This will also help prevent errors when trying to use the string representation of an `_id`: `Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'ObjectId'` Or form POSTs having a null value for `_id`. Unfortunately, searching for those errors doesn't point to this solution, even though it's the same solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it with a Class Map - this is the way to do it:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<i_User>(cm =>
{
  cm.AutoMap();
  cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(x => x.Id)
    .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance));
});
```

Comment: This is a very nice way where POCO remains clean which is my main concern. But it will actually store Id as string in Mongo. The ideal would be to have ObjectId representation in database and string representation in POCO. Is that possible?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I guess you can modify the C# driver.
The purpose of using the ObjectId is it only takes 12 bytes and has a build in timestamp. Why not use ObjectId in your domain entities?

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I usually want to have my domain layer independant of storage layer technique. But I guess everything is a trade off.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a more generic approach using **conventions**.
This approach allows your to setup rules for all models in one place.

First. Add a convention for ID generator

```
public class IdGeneratorConvention : ConventionBase, IPostProcessingConvention
{
    public void PostProcess(BsonClassMap classMap)
    {
        var idMemberMap = classMap.IdMemberMap;
        if (idMemberMap == null || idMemberMap.IdGenerator != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        idMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
    }
}
```

Second. Register our convention. `Register` method must be called **before the first query**.

```
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack { new IdGeneratorConvention() };
ConventionRegistry.Register("Pack", conventionPack, x => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with the ASP minimal APIs and with `record` types for models, here is what works for me.

[Basic custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#sample-basic-converter):

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class ObjectIdJsonConverter : JsonConverter<ObjectId> {
  public override ObjectId Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert,
    JsonSerializerOptions options) => new ObjectId(reader.GetString());

  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ObjectId value,
    JsonSerializerOptions options) => writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}
```

The record:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson;

public record User(
  [property: JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdJsonConverter))]
  ObjectId Id)
```

In the controller:

```cs
app.MapGet("/user/{id}",
  async (string id, UserService userService) => {
    var user = await userService.Find(id);
    return Results.Json(user);
  });
```