# MVC4 WebApi Serialization/Deserialization MongoDB ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, deserialization, asp.net-mvc-4, restsharp

I am using MVC4 WebApi with a RestSharp client and I am struggling to get ObjectIds to serialize (or deserialize) properly.

I have a basic class like so:

```
public class User
{

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

What is the best/proper way to deserialize this object on the client?  Everything I have tried the Id property is of value ObjectId.Empty.

### Update

I have tried a creating a different ObjectIdDeserializers.  Below is an example of a deserializer and the client and sample json that is being sent back to the client.

```
public class ObjectIdDeserializer : IDeserializer
{

    public string RootElement { get; set; }
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    public T Deserialize<T>(RestSharp.IRestResponse response)
    {
        return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(response.Content);
    }

}
```

In RestSharp I have added the following line to call the above deserializer:

```
_client.AddHandler("application/json", new ObjectIdDeserializer());
```

And some sample json looks like this:

```
"User":
{
    "Id":
    {
    "_timestamp":1339158960,
    "_machine":7962014,
    "_pid":4040,
    "_increment":9499872
    },
    "FirstName":"Test",
    "LastName":"User"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @AndrewOrsich I just added some more detail.  Thanks for looking and please let me know if you have any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a bunch of searching on SO, I was able to find a simple solution for what I was trying to do.

Using the approach in this answer, the property gets stored as an ObjectId and in code it is just a string.  Exactly what I was hoping to achieve.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982411/360843