# Set mongodb ObjectId as an url parameter on web api 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to pass a mongodb `ObjectId` parameter to controller via the URL **as string**.

I know in MVC you can use ModelBinder.

How I can do that in ASP.NET WebApi 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

For using ObjectId type in controller like this:

```
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(ObjectId id)
```

see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107413/908936

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web API has the same [detault route principle](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) as MVC.

To be able to pass a value that is mapped directly then to your parameter, just match the property in query string to your method parameter name:

> Call done to: {yourserver}/api/valuesasparam/call?myparam=498574395734958

Your ApiController:

```
public class ValuesAsParamController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Call(string myparam)
    {
        // Do something with your 'myparam' value
    }
}
```

Update:

If you will to get directly the value as an ObjectId, check [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/) for Model binding. and the follwing code to convert your string to an ObjectId:

```
MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.Parse(myparam);
```

Comment: I don't want to convert the parameter in the controller, I want to set the parameter as ObjectId and it will automatically convert the string to ObjectId

Comment: The way to do it is to bulid up a ModelBinder to transform the string to ObjectId, check my post update

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942824/mvc4-webapi-serialization-deserialization-mongodb-objectid) is another **simple solution**. hope helps someone.