# Web API 2.0 JSON Object Serialization Error

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am running into an issue where I am storing Mongo Documents using a class hierarchy as follows:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(DatePriceChangeRuleEntity), typeof(QuantityPriceChangeRuleEntity))]
//***[JsonConverter(typeof(PriceChangeRuleConverter))]***
public partial class ProductPriceChangeRuleEntity
```

As can be seen, this ProductPriceChangeRule has 2 known types viz: DatePriceChangeRule and QuantityPriceChangeRule. These are currently being persisted on Mongo correctly with the right discriminator because I am using the BsonKnownTypes attribute (which is similar to IsClassRegistered call) in Json.net.

These are persisted on Mongo as shown:

```
[{
"_t" : "QuantityPriceChangeRuleEntity",
"_id" : ObjectId("52a57fa612a459164cc0d9f2"),
"Value" : "24",
"ValueType" : 3,
"DateCreatedUtc" : new Date("12/9/2013 00:30:30"),
"DateModifiedUtc" : new Date("12/9/2013 00:30:30"),
"QuantityTrigger" : 3
}]
```

As you can see, I have a Quantity Price change rule with a discriminator correctly identified. When I query the MongoDb, I get the correct de-serialization as well.

However, when I try to return these using the Web API, I get the following error:

```
$id: "1",
message: "An error has occurred.",
exceptionMessage: "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for    content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
exceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException",
stackTrace: null,
innerException: {
$id: "2",
message: "An error has occurred.",
exceptionMessage: "Specified cast is not valid.
```

Now, I think that the WebAPi cannot figure out the Inheritance hierarchy because there's no converter present for it. So I added the converter (as shown in code here):

```
public class PriceChangeRuleConverter : JsonCreationConverter<ProductPriceChangeRuleEntity>
{

    protected override ProductPriceChangeRuleEntity Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        if (FieldExists("QuantityTrigger", jObject))
        {
            return new QuantityPriceChangeRuleEntity();
        }
        else if (FieldExists("EffectiveDateFrom", jObject))
        {
            return new DatePriceChangeRuleEntity();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private bool FieldExists(string fieldName, JObject jObject)
    {
        return jObject[fieldName] != null;
    }

}
```

However, when I do this, I now get an error on JsonCreationConverter on the WriteJson method.

```
public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Just an update that I tried adding WriteJson method, but it spits out an empty JSON: public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            T t = (T)value;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, t);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, it turns out that the issue wasn't the Inheritance hierarchy after all. The culprit is the ObjectId. I tested out by adding a JsonIgnore on the ObjectId and everything started working. After further research I was able to find this:

[MongoDB C#: ID Serialization best pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695730/mongodb-c-id-serialization-best-pattern/7982411#7982411)

This should answer my own question :)