# cannot parse json serialized string with mongo db object id as well as "\"

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, mongodb

I have a controller, which will return an json serialized string in a Get operation:

```
data='[{"user":"CORP\\\\test","id":55cca31dd40238220c11d5a7}]'
```

However, in my angular JS layer, the json parse cannot work:

```
JSON.parse(data)
(program):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c
```

I tried and turns out it is the returned string should be:

```
data='[{"user":"CORP\\\\\\\\test","id":"55cca31dd40238220c11d5a7"}]'
```

(there are two more \, and there should be double quote for "id").

The strange thing is, I get the json string from .NET class:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

And, below is the model class:

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

[BsonElement("User")]
public string User;
```

Anybody know how to resolve this issue to make the json parse in js code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ObjectID to have quotes around it, I believe you need to change the type of the ID property to string as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982411/4843485).

Comment: Yes this answered my question. Thanks!